# Vaadin table clickable url

Tags: vaadin

How I can make url's clickable in `Table`

```
 Table documentTable = new Table();

 documentTable.setContainerDataSource(new BeanItemContainer<>(MyClass.class, myClasses));
```

In MyClass I have

> String url;

I want to display this url as link in my table.

Comment: @Soorapadman Can you explain please? Using my example. I want link in my column like this - [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a generate column to the table that "shadows" the original field/property and that column generator adds a link component to the cell. Here's an example by using Java 8:

```
table.addGeneratedColumn("url", (source, itemId, columnId) ->
  new Link("Click me", new ExternalResource("" + source.getContainerProperty(itemId, columnId).getValue()))
);
```

Comment: Sounds solid. I'll try and let you know